# Android string convert to date fails

Tags: android, date, time

I am trying to convert a string into a Date in java.
I tried all the ways but i always get wrong format.
Here is my code:

```
String datum = curTAB.getString(6);
            DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy.MM.dd.HH:mm:ss");

            try {
                Date date = formatter.parse(datum);
                DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy.MM.dd.HH:mm:ss", Locale.ENGLISH);
                Date result =  df.parse(datum);
                System.out.println("This should be the formatted date: "+date);                 
                //Log.i("asd",""+ date);
                datumLista.add(date);
                datumok = new Date[datumLista.size()];
                datumLista.toArray(datumok);
            } catch (ParseException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

and the result:

what i get:

```
Wed Jan 29 11:55:23 CET 2014
```

what i want:

```
Date formattedDate;
formattedDate =    2014.01.29.11:55:23
```

how can i solve this?

Edit:
okay now here is what i am trying:

```
datumLista.add(df.parse(datum));
```

but if i print it it gave:

```
 Wed Dec 11 13:16:28 CET 2013
```

again :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
        SimpleDateFormat formatter, FORMATTER;
        formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM d HH:mm:ss zzz yyyy");
        String oldDate = "Wed Jan 29 11:55:23 CET 2014";
        Date date;
        try {
            date = formatter.parse(oldDate);
            FORMATTER = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy.MM.dd.HH:mm:ss");
            String newdateforprint = FORMATTER.format(date) ;
            System.out.println("new date= " + newdateforprint);
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Your mistake was

```
        DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy.MM.dd.HH:mm:ss");
```

here date format should be `EEE MMM d HH:mm:ss zzz yyyy`

Answer (score 0):

change to:

```
System.out.println("This should be the formatted date: "+df.format(date));
```

Date object just contains a long value representing time.

Every time you want it in a certain format you use `SimpleDateFormat`'s `format` to get it in a particular format.

When you call `parse` on `SimpleDateFormat` object it expects a string in given format and create a date object that has respective long value of the date.

change to:

```
        String datum = curTAB.getString(6);
        DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy.MM.dd.HH:mm:ss");

        try {
            Date date = formatter.parse(datum);
            datumLista.add(date);
            datumok = new Date[datumLista.size()];
            datumLista.toArray(datumok);
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

and when you get it you can simply say:

```
       for(int i=0;i<datumLista.size();i++)
          System.out.println("This should be the formatted date: "+formatter.format(datumLista.get(i)));
```

Comment: please check my updated question. because if i want to 'datumLista.add(datumLista.add(date));' i cant

Comment: is datumLista list of Date object or list of stringd

Comment: List<Date> datumLista = new ArrayList<Date>();

Comment: what is the value of String datum ?

Answer (score 0):

You need use your SimpleDateFormat to convert your date into another string.

> String FormatedDate = df.format(date);

Comment: i use this: Date result =  df.parse(datum);
but when i add the date to a Date array it chaning: datumLista.add(result); Wed Jan 29 11:55:23 CET 2014
:(

Comment: They all need to be formatted into strings. So result.format(date) should work.

Comment: but i need it in Date object the formatted stiring into a formatted DAte object

Comment: I don't think its possible

Comment: but how should i do it?

Comment: I don't understand why you need to save it ready formatted as a date. Just store it as a timestamp and then parse it back to a date later then format it once you want to show it to a user.